# VB get cursor that returns a function in postgresql

Tags: vb.net, postgresql, odbc

I am using postgresql and vb, and I want to obtner in vb the result of a function that returns a cursor, but I have only been able to make it return the name of the cursor, and I do not want that, but the cursor data.

This is the code :

```
Sub BUSQUEDA(ByRef OBJ As Object, ByVal STR_VALOR As String, ByVal INT_TIPO As Integer, ByVal STR_OPERACION As String)

    Dim CONECTION As New OdbcConnection
    Try
        CONECTION.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SEAU.My.MySettings.FARMACIA_ISABEL_DBConnectionString_64").ConnectionString + ";pwd=xxxxx"

        Dim COMMAND As OdbcCommand = New OdbcCommand(" SELECT SP_BUSQUEDA_DGV('" + STR_VALOR + "'," + CStr(INT_TIPO) + ",'" + STR_OPERACION + "','CURSOR_BUSQ'); " +
                                                         " FETCH ALL IN ""CURSOR_BUSQ"";", CONECTION)

        Dim DA As New OdbcDataAdapter
        Dim DT As New DataTable

        CONECTION.Open()
        DA.SelectCommand = COMMAND
        DA.Fill(DT)
        OBJ = DT
        CONECTION.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception

        If (CONECTION.State = ConnectionState.Open) Then
            CONECTION.Close()
        End If
        Throw ex

    End Try

End Sub
```

I'd appreciate your help

Comment: Can you reformulate your question? I cannot see the how it is related to the code you provided.

Comment: hello, I can not get the cursor data, using vb